# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).append is not a function error

Tags: jquery

now i have this code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>append demo</title>
<style>
div {
background: yellow;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hhh">I would like to say: </div>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("hhh");
$(x).prepend("Hello ");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but when i run it in google chrom browser didn't run and give me this error in console (Uncaught TypeError: $(...).append is not a function) i try it in jsfiddle and it work but i don't know why it don't work with me can any one help me

Comment: You didn't initialize jQuery

Comment: [The code you provided is working](http://jsfiddle.net/qho5vmo4/)

Comment: @WesFoster what does that mean? There is nothing to `initialize`

Comment: @WesFoster If you're referring to `$(document).ready...` it's not needed in this case because the script tag utilizing jQuery is at the end of the document so all html elements are already loaded on the page

Comment: Where are you calling `append`?

Comment: To clarify, is the error that `.append()` is not a function or that `.prepend()` is not a function? You're saying one thing and showing another. If it's `.append()` is not a function then you haven't posted the relevant code...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code shown. Perhaps you are using this in another page where `$` alias is something other than jQuery

Comment: You may want to reference the [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) documentation as well. `.prepend()` takes a parameter `content` (in the context of your usage) which should be: _"DOM element, array of elements, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements."_ While the browser will most certainly let you prepend the text _"Hello "_, it doesn't really fit any of the items listed above because it's technically not an HTML string.

Comment: If you get the error in chrome console regarding the $(...), you need to check if the jquery-1.10.2.js is even loaded from the cdn.

Comment: try with google cdn `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are calling jquery library before your code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){       
       $('#hhh').prepend("Hello ");
    });
</script>
```

If you want to use only javascript try:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("hhh").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", "<div>Hello </div>");
</script>
```

Or:

```
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("hhh");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = 'Hello';
  x.appendChild(div);
</script>
```

Comment: give me this error : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function

Comment: Looks like you are not calling jquery library correctly, check my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should get your x element as a jQuery element.

```
var x = $("#hhh");
```

Comment: you can... but this doesn't explain OP having a problem

Comment: give me this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepend' of null